# Archiving data in google sheets - multiple rows and multiple columns

Tags: google-sheets, archive

Hello everyone I am attempting to modify a script that I found in this post ([Archiving in Google Spreadsheets with Date Using Apps Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14370268/archiving-in-google-spreadsheets-with-date-using-apps-script)).  The goal is to set it up on a time trigger/button to a specific range of cells into a sheet within the same workbook.  When it is archived it should overwrite the previously archived data within the range of cells on the "archive" sheet.  I have played with this script with this suggested script from this post and removed the "delete" and "priorities" components of the action, but am still having problems getting it to simply overwrite what is already there.  I will continue to work with it withing my limited knowledge as I continue to learn, but would greatly appreciate any help or tips.  Or if their is a preexisting code that would serve the purpose that I have missed I would love to hear about it.

Thank you for any insight you can provide and for all the help in the past.

*and thanks to Jad and the User1786546 for the original posting.

Answer (score 0):

I had a quick look at the script post.
If you wanted it to delete the archive data before writing to it, you might need to clear the contents of the sheet first before writing the data.

```
targetsheet.clearContent();
```

This will clear the whole target sheet, (the target sheet is a variable in the script you linked to, this name can be changed),  including column headers.
If this is undesirable, then you may wish to use

```
 getRange().clearContent();
```

Please see this link for more info.
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#clearContent()

If you still need further help, try sharing a dummy spreadsheet, with realistic data and sheets.

Comment: Thank you very much for the feedback.  I will be working on this project over the coming week and will give it a shot.  Again Thank You!